# Android EditTextPreference style

Tags: java, android, styles, android-edittext, edittextpreference

In my app in setings I use EditTextPreference , and on android API uder 11 edittext field has black background and black text color.
How can I chenge EditTextPreferences background color ?

I tried: 
in theme :

```
<item name="android:editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>
```

in style:

```
<style name="EditTextAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>
```

If I set style to :

```
<style name="EditTextPreferences" parent="android:Preference.DeviceDefault.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
  </style>
```

And theme to :

```
<item name="android:editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/EditTextPreferences</item>
```

I got error:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Preference.DeviceDefault.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference'.
```

Answer (score 8):

I have been trying to figure this out as well for the past couple of days. I've found that all the `EditTextPrefence` extends is `AlertDialog` and `EditText`. So if you can style both of those in your theme, you will find the result you are looking for in a `EditTextPreference`. Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/greyscale2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/greyscale16</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/LightTextView</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/LightButton</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/LightEditText</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/LightDialog</item>
    <item name="android:dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/LightDialog</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/greyscale2</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/greyscale1</item>
</style>

<!-- TextView -->
<style name="LightTextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/greyscale16</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<!-- Button -->
<style name="LightButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/greyscale16</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/light_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>

<style name="LightCheckBox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:background">@color/greyscale2</item>
</style>

<style name="LightEditText" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@color/greyscale1</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@color/greyscale2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/greyscale16</item>
    <item name="android:button">@style/DarkButton</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">number</item>
</style>

<style name="LightDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/greyscale2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/greyscale16</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/LightTextView</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/LightButton</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/greyscale14</item>
</style>
```

Notice the 
        `<item name="android:dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/LightDialog</item>` attribute in my base theme. I found the styleable resource [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html), more specifically alertDiaolg [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme_alertDialogTheme) (Note: These can also be found in your SDK directory on your computer)

I hope this at least heads you in the right direction, I have been struggling to figure this out (my first theme in my apps). Happy Coding!

Comment: `android:alertDialogTheme` did it for me! I just wanted to style the little sub-dialogs that appear when you press e.g. `EditTextPreference`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zr0VUzY.jpg]

I think the effect you've observed is a bug in the Gingerbread emulator.
After changing the activity's theme and restarting the emulator the EditTextPreference appeared as above.

Answer (score 0):

First extend `EditTextPreference` and override `onPrepareDialogBuilder`, inverting background color for versions below Honeycomb:

```
public class CustomEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    /**
     * Prepares the dialog builder to be shown when the preference is clicked.
     * Use this to set custom properties on the dialog.
     * <p>
     * Do not {@link AlertDialog.Builder#create()} or
     * {@link AlertDialog.Builder#show()}.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);
    }
}
```

Then replace in your `preferences.xml` all

```
<EditTextPreference ... />
```

with

```
<your.package.CustomEditTextPreference ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when I switched to the API v21 AppCompat (I think - it previously used to work just fine at least).
My solution was to define the style for android:editTextStyle explicitly in my theme - here is my complete styles.xml:

```xml
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

The result is an editText that looks the same as in @Jesse Webb's screenshot.